# jQuery : extract tag from data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

With jQuery v3.2, I want to extract and remove "H1" from AJAX data :

```
$('.version-modal-show').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success:function(d) {
            console.log(d);
            modal.setBody(d);
            modal.open();                
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

*console.log(d)* return html brut :

```
<h1>
    <i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    Centre d&#039;intérêt « TESTb »
</h1>
<p class="text-center">
    <a href="/app_dev.php/administration/hobbies" class="btn btn-secondary">
        <i class="fa fa-backward" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Retour aux centres d&#039;intérêts
    </a>
</p>
```

I want to remove the `h1` from the `modal.setBody()` but put it in the `modal.setTitle()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)ed content

```
modal.setTitle($(d).filter('h1').prop('outerHTML'));
modal.setBody($(d).filter('p.text-center').prop('outerHTML'));
```